# iPhone can't communicate to paired bluetooth low energy device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have got an iPhone problem. Step by step my problem:

1. I discover, connect and pair (bond) my iPhone to BLE device.
2. After some characteristic communication I manually leave the app and disconnect.
3. PROBLEM. When I try to pair and communicate again it is impossible because iPhone shows "connected" or either "not
   connected" to device in "my devices" section in settings. When I try
   to search for devices in app iPhone can't find anything because
   iPhone acts like the device is already found.

How to solve this problem? Because now the only way is to forget the device in settings (delete from "my devices" manually) and only then it is possible to pair and connect..

EDIT:

```
     - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
          if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
               [self scanForPeripherals];
           }
      }

    - (int)scanForPeripherals {
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey,
                                 nil];

        //NSLog(@"%@",@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]);

        [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
        return 0;
      }

    - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
        NSLog(@"didConnectPeripheral");

            // Clear the data
            [self.data setLength:0];

            // Discover callbacks
            peripheral.delegate = self;

            [peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]];
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to discover and connect to your device. Once you have connected once you can save the device Id and simply connect when you discover it again. There is no need for pairing.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I made pairing mode for secure connection. Actually   iPhone reconnect to device in simple way but it can't communicate. Code for discover and connection should be correct.

My term app in pc shows these records:
1. Connection: Peer Passcode:252860
Connected
Bonded
MLDP
1Connection End
2. Next times:
Connected

Comment: I mean once paired you don't need to re-pair, you can simply connect. You say your code should be correct, but then you say it isn't working, so something isn't correct. Without showing some code, however, no one  can help you

Comment: Thanks for answer. I added some code to my question. But IMO that code may not be the problem. Other data exchange apps act the same and after pairing next time connects but can't communicate. Maybe the problem is in peripheral side and device code is not correct? Literally app is connecting but when trying to send some commands there is no reaction and peripheral doesn't receive anything.

Comment: I had the same problem when stopping the app from Xcode.
Try this: connect to the peripheral -> turnoff bluetooth on the peripheral->stop the app->run it again.
If the peripheral can be discovered then you need a clean disconnect from the peripheral at applicationWillTerminate